# How to revert app icon back to original in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, appicon

I have successfully changed my app icon into an alternate icon on iOS.

However, I am wondering if it is possible to revert the changed icon back to the original one, that is in Assets folder without having to add it as an alternate icon in the Info.plist file.

I tried it and it returns the following error "The file doesn't exist."

I'm hoping there is a way to do it without having to add the images somewhere other than inside the Assets folder...

Thanks a lot,

Paprika

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply specify `nil` for the alternate icon name:

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/2806818-setalternateiconname)

> **alternateIconName**
>
> Specify `nil` if you want to display the app’s primary icon, which you declare using the CFBundlePrimaryIcon key.